# Merging or transposing data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Data structure as follows:

```
ID    Oper     DateTime
3849  Login   2019-12-17 06:30:57.500
3849  Logout  2019-12-17 15:46:37.880
3849  Lunch   2019-12-17 12:16:11.373
3849  LunEnd  2019-12-17 12:46:26.807
3862  Login   2019-12-17 06:30:57.500
3862  Logout  2019-12-17 15:46:37.880
3862  Logout  2019-12-17 15:46:38.280
3862  Lunch   2019-12-17 12:16:11.373
3862  LunEnd  2019-12-17 12:46:26.807
```

---

Result Format:

```
ID               Login              Lunch                    LunEnd                      Logout
3849  2019-12-17 06:30:57.500   2019-12-17 12:16:11.373  2019-12-17 12:46:26.807   2019-12-17 15:46:37.880
3862   2019-12-17 06:30:57.500   2019-12-17 12:16:11.373   2019-12-17 12:46:26.807   2019-12-17 12:46:26.807
```

Please suggest a method.

Regards

Comment: The term you are looking for is `PIVOT`.

Comment: how do you get `Logout 2019-12-17 12:46:26.807` for `3862` ? Will you have multiple `login / logout` pair per day ? How about cross day ?

Comment: 1) Source data values do not match final result values. 2) Unclear how to determine what record of 2 records with `(3862, 'Logout')` must be ignored. 3) Does the time order in the subdata pack `(Login -> Lunch -> LunEnd -> Logout)` must be observed?

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be something like...

```
declare @t table (id int, Oper  varchar(50), DateTime DateTime)

insert into @t (id,Oper, DateTime) 
values( 3849, 'Login', '2019-12-17 06:30:57.500'),
(3849, 'Login',  '2019-12-17 06:30:57.500'),
(3849, 'Logout', '2019-12-17 15:46:37.880'),
(3849, 'Lunch',  '2019-12-17 12:16:11.373'),
(3849, 'LunEnd', '2019-12-17 12:46:26.807'),
(3862, 'Login',  '2019-12-17 06:30:57.500'),
(3862, 'Logout', '2019-12-17 15:46:37.880'),
(3862, 'Logout', '2019-12-17 15:46:38.280'),
(3862, 'Lunch',  '2019-12-17 12:16:11.373'),
(3862, 'LunEnd', '2019-12-17 12:46:26.807'),
(3862, 'Login',  '2019-12-18 06:30:57.500'),
(3862, 'Logout', '2019-12-18 15:46:37.880'),
(3862, 'Logout', '2019-12-18 15:46:38.280'),
(3862, 'Lunch',  '2019-12-18 12:16:11.373'),
(3862, 'LunEnd', '2019-12-18 12:46:26.807');


WITH X AS (
SELECT *
    , Cast([DateTime] AS DATE) AS [Date]
FROM @t 
)
SELECT id , [Date] , [Login] , [Lunch] , [LunEnd], [Logout]
FROM X
    PIVOT (
            MAX([DateTime])
            FOR Oper
            IN ([Login] , [Lunch] , [LunEnd], [Logout])
        )p
```

### Result:

```
+------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|  id  |    Date    |          Login          |          Lunch          |         LunEnd          |         Logout          |
+------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3849 | 2019-12-17 | 2019-12-17 06:30:57.500 | 2019-12-17 12:16:11.373 | 2019-12-17 12:46:26.807 | 2019-12-17 15:46:37.880 |
| 3862 | 2019-12-17 | 2019-12-17 06:30:57.500 | 2019-12-17 12:16:11.373 | 2019-12-17 12:46:26.807 | 2019-12-17 15:46:38.280 |
| 3862 | 2019-12-18 | 2019-12-18 06:30:57.500 | 2019-12-18 12:16:11.373 | 2019-12-18 12:46:26.807 | 2019-12-18 15:46:38.280 |
+------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement:

```
declare @t table (id int, Oper  varchar(50), DateTime DateTime)

insert into @t (id,Oper, DateTime) 
values( 3849, 'Login', '2019-12-17 06:30:57.500'),
(3849, 'Login',  '2019-12-17 06:30:57.500'),
(3849, 'Logout',  '2019-12-17 15:46:37.880'),
(3849, 'Lunch',  '2019-12-17 12:16:11.373'),
(3849, 'LunEnd',  '2019-12-17 12:46:26.807'),
(3862, 'Login',  '2019-12-17 06:30:57.500'),
(3862, 'Logout',  '2019-12-17 15:46:37.880'),
(3862, 'Logout',  '2019-12-17 15:46:38.280'),
(3862, 'Lunch',  '2019-12-17 12:16:11.373'),
(3862, 'LunEnd', '2019-12-17 12:46:26.807');

--select * from @t 

 SELECT 
       id,  
       MAX(CASE oper WHEN 'Login' THEN DateTime ELSE 0 END) AS 'Login',
       MAX(CASE oper WHEN 'Logout' THEN DateTime ELSE 0 END) AS 'Logout',
       MAX(CASE oper WHEN 'Lunch' THEN DateTime ELSE 0 END) AS 'Lunch', 
       MAX(CASE oper WHEN 'LunEnd' THEN DateTime ELSE 0 END) AS 'LunEnd' 
    FROM @t
    GROUP BY id
```

Results:

```
id              Login              Logout                   Lunch                 LunEnd
3849    2019-12-17 06:30:57.500 2019-12-17 15:46:37.880 2019-12-17 12:16:11.373 2019-12-17 12:46:26.807
3862    2019-12-17 06:30:57.500 2019-12-17 15:46:38.280 2019-12-17 12:16:11.373 2019-12-17 12:46:26.807
```